# Error after running NPM start on react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have copied a project from a previous machine to my current machine. after running 
`npm install`
And
`npm start`
my terminal gives this error

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! renew_react@0.1.0 start: 'react-scripts start'
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the renew_react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
 additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/TimLowe/.npm/_logs/2018-05-04T15_10_08_807Z-debug.log

the code in`_logs/2018-05-04T15_10_08_807Z-debug.log` is:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v10.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~prestart: renew_react@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: renew_react@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/project4_Renew/Renew/renew_react/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
9 verbose lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/project4_Renew/Renew/renew_react
10 silly lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 info lifecycle renew_react@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: renew_react@0.1.0 start:`react-scripts start
`12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
13 verbose pkgid renew_react@0.1.0
14 verbose cwd /Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/project4_Renew/Renew/renew_react
15 verbose Darwin 15.6.0
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
17 verbose node v10.0.0
18 verbose npm  v5.6.0
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error renew_react@0.1.0 start:`react-scripts start
`23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the renew_react@0.1.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Any ideas on how I can get react to start on my machine?

Comment: Backup your package-lock.json, remove it from the directory, do an `npm install` & `npm start`. If it works it might be something funny with your lock file.

Comment: Did you setup your project using create-react-app (react-scripts comes with it)? Could be fixed with a global update to create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

I had a somewhat similar experience but in my case it was a project that I'm working on my same machine. I'd turn off PC, come after a few days to continue but when I run `npm start` I'd get the error you are having.

This is how I resolved it:

- Navigated to my project directory
- `rm -rf node_modules` to delete the node modules folder
- `rm package-lock.json`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install`
- `npm start`

I ran into a similar error again, this time I had already uploaded my project in git, so each time I want to work on it, I'd do a `git pull project_url` then: 
- `npm install`
- `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually install the [`create-react-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) package again. It will install all of it's dependencies onto your new machine, including `react-scripts`.

`npm install create-react-app`

It should be installed as a global and not part of any specific project.